# Spawning UIView every second at random CGPoint in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, nstimer

I am trying to "spawn" a UIView with a random UIColor as its background at a random CGPoint. I am using the code below which compiles fine with no bugs or anything but when it runs in the simulator I click start(the button on the first ViewController) but then go to ViewTwo but nothing happens(no "enemies" are spawned). Thank you for any help.

```
import UIKit

var randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: Int(arc4random()%1000), y: Int(arc4random()%1000))

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var startGameButton: UIButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}

class ViewTwo : UIViewController {

    var timer = NSTimer()

    func randomColor() -> UIColor {
        let red = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue = CGFloat(drand48())
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    func spawnEnemy() {
        let enemy: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        enemy.backgroundColor = randomColor()
        enemy.center = randomPoint
        self.view.addSubview(enemy)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("spawnEnemy"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your randomPoint needs to be recalculated in spawnEnemy, and is generating a random x y from 0 to 1000 (and should also be a float) It will likely be off the screen.

Comment: would something like let randomPoint: CGPoint = CGPoint(x:CGFloat(arc4random()%320),y: CGFloat(arc4random()%528))

Comment: So what I said above does work with my 4-inch ViewController in Xcode. However, all the happens after I click start is that one spawns and the color changes every second based off the NSTimer. How can I fix my code so they keep spawning in and now just the color

Comment: As I said, you need to move assignment of randomPoint into your spawnEnemy() method. Right now randomPoint is only being assigned once.

Comment: I go tit to work by putting randomPoint in a function that returns a CGPoint and then just returning a randomPoint